# Is there measurable heat at the point of contact with a material subject to light that is deliberately set up to interfere with itself?

Tags: visible-light, interference, interferometry

When a laser is spaced to produce two beams separated by exactly 1/2 the applicable wavelength, interference occurs, and there's no visible light, at least to the human eye.

But is there heat generated at the point of contact between the light and some material?

If not, how is momentum conserved?

Is the conclusion then that even a high energy laser would fail to produce heat if you simply space the beams appropriately?

And if so, then how is the resultant light any different from a light that has twice the applicable frequency?

Comment: see this answer https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/646305/why-doesnt-incoherent-light-cancel-itself-out/646445#646445

Comment: any comment on the answer?

Comment: I think you need to provide a source for the claim that the laser actually stops drawing electricity, which I've never heard of before.

Comment: https://www.rp-photonics.com/alignment_sensitivity_of_optical_resonators.html   " " The performance of a laser often deteriorates seriously when one of its components is misaligned. Typical effects are a drop of output power, a ....."

Comment: If you split a laser into 2 paths you can adjust one path length to be n+1/2 lambda and you will get no transmission, if the other path is n lambda it will get all the transmission.  If both are n+1/2 you will get zero transmission!

Comment: Since you are a fan of Feynman check out https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_19.html . A photon   " smells all the paths in the neighborhood and chooses the one that has the least action by a method analogous to the one by which light chose the shortest time ..."

Answer (score 0):

Setting the mirrors for destructive interference causes the laser to actually stop lasing, this can be evidenced by noting the loss in power consumption of the laser power supply. External mirrors are no different than the internal mirrors of the laser .... upset the path length and the laser does not lase.

Light never cancels itself out, if it did that would be a violation of conservation of energy.

The word "interference" was initially used in 1801 for Young's DSE ... as the image was similar to water wave interference. Essentially what you/we are still taught today is based on 1801! Quantum optics courses teach it correctly. It is note worthy that the mathematics of "interference" i.e. waves 180 degrees out of phase is very similar to the quantum math i.e. Feynman path integral.

Light is created by an excited electron/atom and only absorbed by another electron/atom.